# MYSQL why would ORDER BY DESC fail but ORDER BY ASC work?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why would only one of these queries work?

Works:

```
SELECT *
FROM `global_rank`
WHERE rank_type = 2
  AND rank < 1531.26367188
  AND id <> 103
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

Fails (ie returns 0 rows):

```
SELECT *
FROM `global_rank`
WHERE rank_type = 2
  AND rank < 1531.26367188
  AND id <> 103
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure it is on the very same table, with the very same data?  Otherwise, it *has to* work.

Comment: yes, I'm running this in phymyadmin and for some reason the second one returns nothing

Comment: rank_type and rank  are indexed and I believe it has something to do with mysql indexing not supporting reverse ordering?

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem with your sql queries they are flawless.

Please check the way you are validating your query results. I know sometimes we overlook the results ( common human error).

Answer (score 2):

After pondering this for a few hours, I'm almost sure it has to be a corrupted index problem.  Drop the index on `rank` and re-add it to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: I can confirm I had a similar problem just now and it was a corrupted index.